# Job Scheduler Android

Tags: android, networking, background

Actually! I want to make app which continuously detects either Internet connection is connected or disconnected.For this i am using Job Scheduler because it also works on Oreo version or above.
For this , I set job Info .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE) because i want onStartJob() get triggered when there is no connection ,but it is not working like that...`

This is the code for making Job.

```
public void scheduleJob(View view) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, ExampleServiceClass.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
            .setMinimumLatency(1000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
    }
}
```

This is the code of class where i extended JobService

```
public class ExampleServiceClass extends JobService {
private static final String TAG = "ExampleJobService";
private boolean jobCancelled = false;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    MainActivity.scheduleTheJob(getApplicationContext());
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
    Toast.makeText(this, "job stopped!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: " I set job Info .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE) because i want onStartJob() get triggered when there is no connection ,but it is not working like that" -- `NETWORK_TYPE_NONE` means "there is no requirement to have a network connection". It does not mean "only invoke the job when there is *no* network connection".

Comment: @CommonsWare:  i dont understand,then what is the benefit of using NETWORK_TYPE_NONE

Comment: It is the default rule for "required network type" and means "there is no particular requirement". It says "you can run this job without caring about the network". Not every job handed to `JobScheduler` needs network access (e.g., making a local backup).

Comment: @CommonsWare:  So how can i triggered onStartJob() method when i want?Or tell me other way to achieve my goal that would work on all devices..thanks in advance

Comment: "So how can i triggered onStartJob() method when i want?" -- `JobScheduler` is not set up for this. Use `ConnectivityManager` to find out when network connections come and go.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  can you assist with code plz